# Python Pygames wait for event

Tags: pygame

Using pygame.event.wait() to decrease system overhead between events. But the way I'm using it seems to filter out most events. Must not be placing it in the right spot in my program.

Can someone please take a look and comment about whether I'm using it wrong?

## run the game loop

LEFT=1

while True:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():

    if event.type == QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()

    elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == LEFT:
        print "You pressed the left mouse button at (%d, %d)" % event.pos
    elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP and event.button == LEFT:
        print "You released the left mouse button at (%d, %d)" % event.pos
pygame.display.update()
pygame.event.wait()
```

Answer (score 2):

`pygame.event.wait` returns the event in question and pops it from the queue, so you have to manage it with the other ones:

```
for event in [pygame.event.wait()]+pygame.event.get():

    if event.type == QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()

    elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == LEFT:
        print "You pressed the left mouse button at (%d, %d)" % event.pos
    elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP and event.button == LEFT:
        print "You released the left mouse button at (%d, %d)" % event.pos
```

Comment: Using this suggested line: ``for event in [pygame.event.wait()]+pygame.event.get():`` greatly reduces CPU usage in games where the CPU runs full-bore when there are no events (compared to ``for event in pygame.event.get():``).  Nice.